# React webpack bundle for production

Tags: reactjs, webpack, bundle, react-redux

I need some help to bundle my output for production but I have no idea how. Here's my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'eval',
    context: __dirname,
    entry: "./js-source/index.jsx",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/scripts",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, 
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ],
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
        }
    }
};
```

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "citygross-store-web",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.14.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-redux": "^4.1.2",
    "react-responsive": "^1.3.0",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-transition-group": "^1.2.0",
    "redux": "^3.1.2",
    "redux-logger": "^2.6.1",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.3.14",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.13.0",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --colors",
    "dev": "webpack --watch --colors"
  },
  "-vs-binding": {
    "ProjectOpened": [
      "dev"
    ]
  }
}
```

How do you usually bundle for production? By adding a command like "npm run build" and having the other settings in that setting?

I would appreciate if someone could help me out how to set this up. Right now I can do "npm run dev" and "npm run build", however there's no difference between using the two more than "run dev" creates a -watcher and build builds the bundle one time.

Answer (score 2):

Set the environment variable `NODE_ENV` to `production` when running your build script.  This will cause the production build of React to be included in the output.

Easiest way is to add another script to your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --colors",
    "buildprod": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --colors",
    "dev": "webpack --watch --colors"
  },
```

Now when you do `npm run buildprod`, you'll get a production build of your code.

Note: if you are on Windows, the above won't work right.  For proper cross-OS you should use `cross-env`:

Install cross-env:

```
npm install cross-env --save-dev
```

or

```
yarn add cross-env --dev
```

Then make your scripts section look like:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --colors",
    "buildprod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --colors",
    "dev": "webpack --watch --colors"
  },
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I get the following message when trying to run "npm run buildprod" now*: Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     NODE_ENV=production webpack --colors

Comment: Am I missing something in my webpack.config to match with the NODE_ENV?

Comment: See the new section for Windows support.

Comment: @Codehiker  For Windows you might also need to use `set NODE_ENV=development`. For my Windows environment I use `set NODE_ENV=production && webpack --config webpack.config.js -p`

Comment: Webpack has an [--env](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-a-function-to-use-env) option as well.